# Submit button is submitting but not saving - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried many things to get the submit button to submit to the database. I'm not getting any errors, and the two error messages for testing, one from the controller, one from the view, are not printing to let me know that it is not working. Upon user hitting submit, it renders and displays the same button- Set Statement, instead of the new text that the user entered. Not sure how to fix or where the problem is.

Here is the code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(TableA Statement)
    {
        var model = new Test.Models.Tables();

        using (var db = new Entities())

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TableA tablea = new TableA();
            tablea.Statement = model.Statement;
            db.TablesA.Add(tablea);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Failed");
        }

    }
```

Main View:

```
<td>
     @if (tablea.Statement != null)
     {
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => tablea.Statement)
     <text>|</text>
     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = tablea.ID })
      }
            else
            {

            Html.RenderAction("PopUp");

            var model = new Test.Models.Tables();

            if (model.Statement != null) {
            <text>Save Successful!</text>
                                        }
                                    }
                           </td>
```

Popup View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="form-horizontal">
      =
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Statement, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Statement)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Statement)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" onsubmit="Create(Statement)" class="btn btn-default">
</div.. etc>
```

Comment: Your Renderaction seen wrong.. try change it to:  `@Html.RenderAction("View", "Controller")`, also you have edit view, so I suppose you received an Id, so you need to call it like `,new {id = model.id}` or whatever you have in your model

Comment: Popup View is a partial view or what?,  I recommend convert it to partial view, and in your controller you can do something like public `ActionResult CreatePartial()
{
    var pages = pageRepository.Pages;
    return PartialView(pages);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup View is a partial view or what?,  I recommend convert it to partial view, and in your controller you can do something like

```
public ActionResult CreatePartial()
{
var pages = pageRepository.Pages;
return PartialView(pages);
}
```

and in your view use

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Popup", "CreatePartial");}
```

if your model of partial is different of model of main view, if not use:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("ViewName")
```